# How can I protect my PHP application folder in Apache (Windows)?

Tags: php, windows, apache, passwords

My PHP app will run on Apache in Windows (XP or 7), but initially an user will be at the same machine using it.

This means the source code will be there at the user's reach.

How can I restrict access to the folders and **non-compiled** PHP files? Is there a way to simply **password-protect** this?

Comment: Probably not really. Can you add some more information about your situation. Does the user have root rights on the machine? Why is compiling the code not an option?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to make a file inaccessible to an administrator without encrypting it. You'd have to run a virtual machine inside the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [suggested by Pekka 웃](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674913/how-can-i-protect-my-php-application-folder-in-apache-windows/14792216#comment20514414_14674913), I set up a [virtual machine](https://www.virtualbox.org) with [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29). Actually, I downloaded one already made from [VirtualBoxImages.com](http://virtualboximages.com/Ubuntu+12.04+i386+Lamp+Tomcat+Server+Virtual+Computer) and adjusted it to my needs (I was even able to set a [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)'d [MySQL](http://blog.winhost.com/using-mysqldump-to-backup-and-restore-your-mysql-databasetables/) backup synchronized with [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx), so cool).

And now all the client needs to do is to run the virtual machine to start my PHP applicaton up. He and everybody in the same network can then access the app (and also the [database](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php)) by typing the virtual machine name in the URL field - thanks to both two network adapters enabled for the virtual machine ([bridge AND host-only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113604/how-to-run-virtualbox-on-bridged-and-host-only-networks)). Plus I can maintain the application remotely by using [WinSCP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/).

Now I have what I asked for: my PHP app is running on Apache. It's inside a Linux's Ubuntu machine, but that it's portably inside Windows XP/7: in the same machine as the client, with the **non-compiled** PHP files **password-protected** by the virtual machine user account.

This ended way better than what I intended, with ease!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way I know of, that can do what you want. The first part is to right click your htdocs folder and click "properties" the next part is to go to the Security tab. Click the edit button. Next give yourself all the rights to the folder and if the other user is a admin then remove privileges for administrators. The last part is to click the Add button and type Users in. You'll then be able to edit permissions on this folder for all the users on the machine. I would remove everything so they can't do anything to your folder.

NOTE: Because you allowed your self, all privileges, the "users" privileges wont apply to you.